# .exe run in matlab does not create two output files like it does when run in command prompt

Tags: matlab, system, exe, output

Okay, I've searched all across this site, without any luck.

Here's my problem:

I have an .exe that produces two output files when run, which it does fine when I actually use the .exe itself.

However, when I run it in MATLAB (yes it actually runs and has identical system messages just like in the command prompt), the two output files are NOT produced. I'm not sure if this is something that can be controlled using system() in MATLAB, or this is a problem with the .exe.

My code to run the .exe (it also takes an input file) is simply this:

`system(['C:\MyProgram.exe ' myInputFile]);`

Any tips, pointers, advice, or solutions are greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you sure it can find the input file?  Are there any program messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `myInputfile` as a string. I guess your program is NOT running, because I'd say your command is not working. Try the following:

```
yourCommand = strcat('c: && MyProgram.exe',{' '},myInputFile);
system( yourCommand{1} );
```

`{' '}` is neccesary, because spaces at the end of strings are ignored.
You can not just type your path into the command line, you need to define the path before and then call the function. As you cannot put all commands in a row, you need to use `&&`, which is like typing `Enter` in the command window.

Comment: Awesome! This worked! Although the same messages that came up in MATLAB still appear, the actual output files are being created.