# Matlab is not running a .exe external program on Windows

Tags: matlab, exe

I'm trying to run .exe code inside Matlab terminal (R2018a) but I'm encountering some problems.

My .exe code runs normally on Windows cmd with the following generic command (**an expected output file is created**)

```
code.exe < input
```

In Matlab I tried 4 approaches:

```
system('code.exe < input');
dos('code.exe < input');
system('code.exe < input', '-echo');
system('set path=%path:C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin\win64;=% & code.exe < input');
```

They are returning the line below and **no output file is created**.

```
ans = -1.0737e+09
```

Adding the "**&**" character at the end of the line of attempt 1, as sugested by [ref](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/179572-running-exe-file-from-mtlab-using-system) and many others,  Matlab opens the Windows cmd in the correct folder but does not execute the .exe code properly (no processes are running in task manager), **no output file is created**, e.g.:

```
system('code.exe < input &');
```

I also tried the suggestion of this reference [.exe run in matlab does not create two output files like it does when run in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950221/exe-run-in-matlab-does-not-create-two-output-files-like-it-does-when-run-in-com) but I was not successful. This reference suggestion is also returning and **no output file is created**: "ans = -1.0737e+09"

Edit:
According to this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/316233-can-t-run-external-program), user Walter Roberson says "-1073741511 is hex C0000139 which appears to correspond to the Windows error code for "Entry point not found". That indicates that you either tried to execute something that was inherently not properly created (such as if you tried to directly execute the DLL that did not have a main program), or else that the program you executed tried to use a DLL that could not be found."

Any insights on how to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with what they are returning? why? what? As far as we can see, code.exe could simply just be a program that reutns that number

Comment: @AnderBiguri When the 'code.exe < input' command is run in Windows cmd, an output file is created with the results. The same is not observed for any of the cases when I try to use the Matlab terminal to execute the command 'code.exe < input', either through the "system" or "dos" function. Also, all files (code.exe, input.exe) are in the same directory (which is the current Matlab directory when I run the commands mentioned above).

Comment: @AnderBiguri According to this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/316233-can-t-run-external-program), user Walter Roberson says "-1073741511 is hex C0000139 which appears to correspond to the Windows error code for "Entry point not found". That indicates that you either tried to execute something that was inherently not properly created (such as if you tried to directly execute the DLL that did not have a main program), or else that the program you executed tried to use a DLL that could not be found."

Comment: MATLAB does change the `PATH` environment variable, which is used to find program dependencies.

Comment: Try `system('code.exe < input', '-echo')`, maybe seeing the error message helps.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried `system('code.exe < input', '-echo');` and change the path as this [reference](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/316233-can-t-run-external-program) executing `system('set path=%path:C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin\win64;=% & code.exe < input');`, both alternatives returned `ans = -1.0737e+09`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo when any test command returns `ans = -1.0737e+09`, Windows cmd doesn't even open (I don't know if it's expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/408044-what-is-the-difference-between-a-system-call-from-matlab-using-system-and-a-command-in-a-cmd-ter#comment_612806) solved my problem.

Basically, You will have to create a batch file similar to the one below and change the Matlab path according to your version.

```
fid = fopen('myBatchFile.bat','w')
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','set path=%path:C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin\win64;=%');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','code.exe < input')
fclose(fid)
system('myBatchFile.bat')
```